# Split a folder before starting script

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

If I have folders, some with 300+ images and some with 40 or less images.

Is there a Javascript (pure Javascript as I am using Photoshop) that can take from folder "ORIGINAL" then if there is more than 50 images in the folder it creates a folder called "SPLIT1" and cuts 50 images in there. Then it looks in "ORIGINAL" again and if there is still 50+ images it creates another folder called "SPLIT2" and carries on until folder "ORIGINAL" has less than 50 or exactly 50 images inside.

Tried hunting but was unable to find anything.

Many Thanks,
:)

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  Have a look at the documentation for the File System Access section of the [Javascript Tools Guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/scripting/estk/javascript_tools_guide.pdf).  You can use the Folder.selectDialog to prompt the user for where you'd like to run the script, and then from there the documentation on Folder and File objects in the ExtendScript Toolkit should get you the rest of the way.